# Can't populate data with binding

Tags: html, knockout.js, sammy.js

This is my first try to make a single page application with HTML5. I'm using jquery, knockout and sammy.

Code: http://codepaste.net/apdrme

The problem is that I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I know it is the following:

```
                this.get("#/", function() {                
                    this.personList(this.persons);
                });
```

But how else can I populate the list?

Answer (score 0):

You would normally use jQuery and an ajax call to populate personList. personList should be an ko.observableArray.

```
this.personList = ko.observableArray();

this.get("#/", function() {                
    $.ajax({url:"/api/persons/", dataType: 'json', success:function(persons){
        this.personList(persons);
    }});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could populate your list as follows:

```
function ViewModel() {    
    this.personList = ko.observableArray([{"name":"Josh"}, {"name":"Barry"}, {"name":"Mike"}]);
};
[...]
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Pay attention to use `ko.observableArray()` at the declaration. So, you could also remove the argument and call `this.personList([{"name":"Josh"}, {"name":"Barry"}, {"name":"Mike"}])` in your main Sammy route and fill the list with other values in another route.

Another mistake is that you have used the with-binding that is not necessary here. Check the [documentation about it](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html).